# Magento block is not showing any content but it the block is being displayed

Tags: blocks, magento-1

I am new to Magento development so forgive me if I am missing a step, I created a `.phtml` file and I have called it inside one of my `cms pages` by using the following

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/shop.phtml"}}
```

and inside my `shop.phtml` is

```
<div>test</div>
```

but nothing is showing even though it is recognizing it see below.

[image]

Comment: Which Magento version are you using?  I believe it looks like 1.9. I ran into an issue once where I had to "allow" blocks coming from core/template to be shown.  This was done through the admin panel for blocks that I added.

Comment: 1.9.2, I've also tried adding it to my base folder in case there was some problem with the themes but it still doesn't output anything.

Comment: Which theme you are used and is cache enable or disable ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file is in right package and theme. As from the screen shot it is searching the file in base/default path.

Copy your file to in base/default path and check if its working.
Then try to find out which theme and package you are using and keep the file in right path to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the permission issue as I think.

You need to give permission from admin to `core/template`

1. Go to `Admin -> System -> Permission -> Blocks`
2. `Add New Block` and add block name `core/template`
3. Set `isAllowed` to `Yes`
4. `Save Block` and clear the `cache`.